# How to generate warning when using static_cast in c++ gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc, static-cast

I need to remove the use of static_cast from the project and prevent normal compilation if static_cast is added, the gcc documentation doesn't say how warnings can be enabled when using static_cast.

I searched the gcc documentation for the static_cast keyword, but did not find anything suitable.

Comment: You may use a `static_assert` that ensures, that derived type inherits the casted type.

Comment: Looks more like a job for a static code checker. Do you have a source control system? Then maybe you can add this as a pre-check-in hook and not allow new code to be checked in if a static_cast is found in the code. Not as early a warning as compilation but enough to prevent it from ending up in a product

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I need to control the use of static_cast for numeric types

Comment: @PepijnKramer Thanks for the hint, there is git, but the problem remains with the removal of the existing use of static_cast

Comment: @Maxim Grep throught the existing code base to find the instances. You would need to do a line by line analysis anyway.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Yes, I considered this option as the last one, if it fails to be done using gcc

Comment: Writing a custom `clang-tidy` check is what I'd go for and then add a pre-commit `git` hook (after first doing a check and cleanup of the entire code base) that runs `clang-tidy` on the code being committed.

Comment: You can't remove a language feature at will. But I believe you might try a trick, like ```#define static_cast```, or by some global define switch, as in VisualC++ is ```/D```

Comment: You probably also want to look at C-style casts, since every `static_cast` could be replaced with a C-style cast. Again, `clang-tidy` can help there, but `g++` can also warn on usage of C-style casts (see the `-Wold-style-cast` option) and with warnings as errors (`-Werror`) that'll keep the C-style casts out.

Comment: May I ask why you don't want static_cast be used in your project? I mean it exists for a reason and has many sane use cases.

Comment: One of the reasons for having named casts is that they're easy to search for. `grep static_cast *.cpp` will find any uses.

Comment: If I had to I'd probably (reluctantly) enforce a requirement to not use `static_cast` through a build script, not the compiler.   For example (under unix) have a makefile force a build to fail if a dependency that executes `grep static_cast <filename>` returns zero.   Bear in mind you'll need to check all headers and other source files `#include`d in your project (although standard headers may legitimately contain `static_cast` - I'd suggest not checking those).

Comment: There are times when `static_cast` is useful, or even necessary.  It's an essential part of CRTP, for example.  I'd just let it be, I really would.

Answer (score 3):

I highly doubt that there is any compiler setting for that in general. `static_cast` is a completely normal feature of the language to use and the preferred way over C-style explicit casts. It is not clear what purpose such a warning would serve. In fact `static_cast` is conventionally used to tell the compiler to *not* warn about otherwise implicit conversions that might be problematic like narrowing conversions.

There is a clang-tidy check `cppcoreguidelines-pro-type-static-cast-downcast` to warn of uses of `static_cast` that are downcasts (which may lead to UB and are recommended by the core guidelines to be replaced with `dynamic_cast`).

Maybe there is also some clang-tidy check or similar that warns if a `static_cast` conversion would also be possible implicitly, but that would probably interfere with the convention mentioned above.

You'll likely need to use an external tool. Something as simple as `grep -R static_assert .` or some `sed`/`awk` to replace uses of `static_assert` in the way you want may be sufficient. If you need to actually modify the parsed AST, you'll probably need to write something e.g. based on Clang's libraries/tooling.

Comment: I'd also be really careful when employing such a measure (which without context sounds rather harsh) that contributors don't just start using c-style casts to get their code accepted.

Comment: @nick Luckily for C-style casts some compilers and clang-tidy do actually have warnings and they make a lot more sense than a warning for a `static_cast` in general.

Answer (score 1):

It can be blocked by `#define`.
This will generate a compile error

```cpp
#define static_cast
int main()
{
    int x = static_cast<int> (3.14);
}
```

Comment: Wonder if some evil code might still pass after that `#define`.... Something like `f(x<static_cast<VarOrType>(5))` (-> `f(x << VarOrType > 5)`). ^_^

Comment: @Jarod42 `f(x<static_cast<VarOrType>(5))` would become `f(x < < VarOrType > 5)` after preprocessing (note the space between the 'less'-symbols). Tokenization happens before the preprocessor runs afaik.

Comment: You could also `#pragma GCC poison static_cast` but this will break every external header that uses a static cast.

Comment: My sample effectively doesn't work (there is indeed extra space). but maybe other strange code might exist.

Comment: @Jarod42 My post is just an idea, a finger pointing at the moon. You can ```#define``` the static_cast as something else. Just thinking about something like ```(2=3)```. Anyway, is highly unlikely that the define will fail, unless you deliberately are trying hard to undermine it.